# Understanding of hBase data storage (webpage) for Nutch

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nutch, distributed-database

I am using HBase as my storage for crawled data by Apache Nutch. A location of my storage is in path /data/hbase/webpage and there I can see a lot of folders like:

```
64b2feb30073eec24d9dba65d421e7f 
482062bc554bd45bf198d9edea971a30
7c8a6eec12d9f6926a1d912be9a0ca81
c1f682541b8d1c0559de6df14ae84e2b
083b28ee75babc718cc28e66b98c9ff5
809eb4bb5f2be087e2c84a2f51d26653
```

and more...

These folders contains another folders like:

```
f  h  il  mk  mtdt  ol  p  recovered.edits  s
```

But it is not so important.

I am writing my own indexer for Nutch to get crawled data from HBase to Solr. I need to put it to Solr in batches because when I run it all, I get OutOfMemory exception.

I would like to ask you if it is possible to get batch ids from my HBase storage (to know which batch ids I have and then I can send it to index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how are you trying to implement your solution: if as a Nutch plugin, a Hadoop MapReduce or a single process script, but I guess this information will be helpful:

- As indicated in [nutch-src/conf/gora-hbase-mapping.xml](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/tags/release-2.2.1/conf/gora-hbase-mapping.xml), batchId is mapped to HBase's column `f:bid`.
- You have to read it using Gora. The instances of `WebPage` have the method `#getBatchId()`. Check the [avro WebPage definition](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/tags/release-2.2.1/src/gora/webpage.avsc) and the [compiled class](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/tags/release-2.2.1/src/java/org/apache/nutch/storage/WebPage.java).

When developing a plugin, much probably you will see a `WebPage` parameter in the interface of the plugin.

If you want to access `batchId` in a *raw way in HBase*, just read the column `f:bid` and consider it the raw text. If I am not wrong, Gora is not writing additional information on strings (unlike when serialized).

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I arrive home from work, I will try it.